# Is there a white labeled RTMFP solution?

Tags: javascript, streaming, adobe, adobe-cirrus

I'm trying to use Adobe Cirrus p2p video chat in my app but i don't have a clue how to implement that especially that i'm a js/php developer, so i'm wondering if there is some JS libraries to make web cam areas and connect/disconnect through that library's methods?

I'm not looking for a whole video chat script, think about how chatroulette implements Cirrus only for the webcam areas.